# Grammar not working (NoViableAltException)

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I'm new to ANTLR and I´m trying to play with it. This is the simplest grammar that I could think and still it is not working (NoViableAltException) when I parse a variable "id123", but it works for "abc1", "ab", "c1d2f3".

I'm using ANTLR 3.1.3 and ANTLRWorks 1.4.

```
options 
{
    language = 'CSharp2';
    output = AST;
}

assign  :   variable '=' value;
value   :   (variable|constant);
variable:   LETTER (LETTER|DIGIT)*;
constant:   (STRING|INTEGER);

DIGIT   :   '0'..'9';
NATURAL :   (DIGIT)+;   
INTEGER :   ('-')? NATURAL; 
REAL    :   (INTEGER '.' NATURAL);

LETTER  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z');

CR      :   '\r'        { $channel = HIDDEN; }; 
LF      :   '\n'        { $channel = HIDDEN; }; 
CRLF    :   CR LF       { $channel = HIDDEN; }; 
SPACE   :   (' '|'\t')  { $channel = HIDDEN; };

STRING  :   '"' (~'"')* '"';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANTLR's lexer tries to match as much as possible. Whenever two (or more) rules match the same amount of characters, the rule defined first will "win". So, whenever the lexer stumbles upon a singe digit, a `DIGIT` token is created, because it is defined before `NATURAL`:

```
DIGIT   :   '0'..'9';
NATURAL :   (DIGIT)+;
```

but for the input `"id123"` the lexer produced the following 3 tokens:

```
LETTER          'i'
LETTER          'd'
NATURAL         '123'
```

because the lexer matches greedily, and therefor a `NATURAL` is created, and *not* three `DIGIT` tokens.

What you should do is make a lexer rule of `variable` instead:

```
assign   :   VARIABLE '=' value;
value    :   (VARIABLE | constant);
constant :   (STRING | INTEGER | REAL);

VARIABLE :   LETTER (LETTER|DIGIT)*;
INTEGER  :   ('-')? NATURAL; 
REAL     :   (INTEGER '.' NATURAL);
SPACE    :   (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')  { $channel = HIDDEN; };
STRING   :   '"' (~'"')* '"';

fragment NATURAL :   (DIGIT)+;   
fragment DIGIT   :   '0'..'9';
fragment LETTER  :   ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z');
```

Also note that I made a couple of lexer rules `fragment`s. This means that the lexer will never produce `NATURAL`, `DIGIT` or `LETTER` tokens. These `fragment` rules can only be used by other lexer rules. In other words, your lexer will only ever produce `VARIABLE`, `INTEGER`, `REAL`, and `STRING` tokens* (so these are the only ones you can use in your parser rules!).

* and `'='` token, of course...

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but now assign doesn´t work. I´m trying "id123 = 2222". I just copied and pasted your answer.